# iPhone how to create splash color functionality

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, pixel-manipulation

I am trying to learn image manipulation and one of the techniques i want to execute is the splash color functionality... which is something like the "Color Splash" app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorsplash/id304871603?mt=8

Specifically I want to start by turning the whole image into grey and then where ever I swipe the pixels should gain their colors back...

Can anyone tell me how I should go about doing this... or give me a link to some code...

greatly appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Have you successfully converted the image to grayscale? Can you determine the area of pixels that need to be re-colorized? Can you find the corresponding pixels in the original color image?